# Visual Studio, отладка разделяемой библиотеки, которая собирается в отдельном решении

Tags: c++, dll, отладка, breakpoint

Рассмотрим следующую ситуацию.

Есть два `cmake`-проекта. Каждый проект генерирует самостоятельное решение. В каждом решении есть только один проект.

1. Исполняемый файл, который грузит и использует динамическую библиотеку;
2. Динамическая библиотека.

Мой вопрос заключается в следующем:

Я хочу отлаживать разделяемую библиотеку. Хочу ставить в исходном коде библиотеки точки останова, но делать это через решение для сборки исполняемого файла, который грузит соответствующую разделяемую библиотеку.

Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: А что, если собрать в дебаг-режиме библиотеку, то не ставятся точки останова или как?

Comment: В решении с исполняемым файлом нет проекта с исходным кодом разделяемой библиотеки.

Comment: как насчет открыть нужный файл поставить в нем точку останова?